# How to change the localized value in to number format in c#

Tags: c#

I have the string value "123,45,67.89". I need to convert this value in to number format as 123,45,67.89. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Well 123,45,67.89 is not a number, so I don't know how could you convert it to number.

Answer (score 5):

Specify the right culture, like `en-GB`:

```
double.Parse("123,45,67.89", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))
```

This will produce a `double` value of `1234567.89`. How you then format it for display is up to you.

Be aware that the thousand separators in that string looks misplaced as you have one group of 3 digits and 2 groups of 2 digits, but it looks as though `double.Parse` and/or that culture doesn't care.

As a test I checked if any of the .NET (or is it Windows?) built-in cultures will format a value as currency into something with groups of 2 but it appears not.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine you would need to remove the commas from the string first.

`str = number.Replace("," , "");`

`str` being the new string and number being the original.

Then if I'm correct to parse in c# you need to do `Double.Parse(str)`.

This should provide you with a double variable to carry out whatever calculations you need

Comment: Technically you're correct but there's another issue which is a `NumberFormat`. In some culture settings `,` sign is used to mark the start of decimal places while in other it uses `.` sign. To get this to work I would suggest using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` to toggle these before switching to correct decimal separator.